# What are the downsides to wrapping your entire javascript library in a try catch block?

Tags: javascript, error-handling

I'm thinking of wrapping my entire javascript library inside a try catch block so that any errors would not cause the third party page using the library to break.

Also, I'd be able to catch errors thrown by my own code and send them to my server.

My only question is are there any potential negative side-effects that could occur from doing this? (performance, error tracking etc.)

Comment: If you make your code error-free, you don't need to catch any errors.

Comment: @Blender of course, but when your code is cast out onto the World Wide Web, there could always be something you hadn't expected

Comment: [performance](http://jsperf.com/try-catch-performance-overhead) for one.

Comment: @user730569: jQuery doesn't wrap itself in a huge `try...catch` block, and I have yet to see any production library that does this. If you test your code thoroughly and a user finds a corner case that breaks your code, an exception will let them report the problem back to you. Shoving problems under the rug won't help anyone.

Comment: @Blender well what this will let us do is make sure that we only receive errors that are related to our own code... that way we wouldn't need people to report these errors to us.

Comment: @user730569: If your users are causing the problems, they aren't using your code correctly. Swallowing all exceptions will make your code undebuggable. That's like getting rid of the error messages in `g++`.

Comment: @Blender sorry if I didn't make it clear, but our library isn't something that developers use to program with, it's just something that they use to automatically add functionality to their website (it's not an api)

Comment: Not sure why this was closed.  There are actual downsides to taking this sort of approach.  It might be nice to share specific experiences with trying to implement this idea, best practices, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Wrapping your library in a `try{}` block is **not** a good idea.  There are a few different issues.  Notably, V8 can't optimize the stack as well inside of a `try{}`, leading to noticeable performance loss.  Wrapping anything that you don't actually expect to `throw` an error is generally not a good practice, as it swallows and hides the errors from the debugging console.

Also, wrapping the library in `try{} catch(e) {}` isn't going to magically catch every error that occurs.  Perhaps your "library" is just a chunk of JavaScript code that executes once as it loads, but most likely you have some sort of asynchronous operations that will cause code to execute in other event loops outside of the `try{}`.  It is important to note that this **WILL NOT** catch:

```
try {
    setTimeout(function() {
        throw "test";
    }, 100);
} catch(e) { 
    console.log( "I got caught" );
}
```

[Try yourself in jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qJemR/)

Luckilly, there is a good place to catch "unhandled" errors - Having a sane `window.onerror` is a pretty good idea for the "first party" developer, but when you are working on a library, you should instead rely on rock-solid unit testing.  Having an obvious, and easy to use bug reporting form for the "first party developer" is also a must.  Trust me, people will complain if your library breaks. :)

P.S. - I found [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/144326/try-catch-in-javascript-isnt-it-a-good-practice) over on programmers SE which should shed some more light on `try{}`

P.P.S. - Found a decent [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/try-catch-performance-overhead) using `try{}` and if you take a look, it seems to suggest that a function which includes a `try{}` block will be less performant.

Comment: +1 Such bad practice (when it actually works and you are catching every error and hiding it) can be named "diaper anti-pattern". It is the name that is pretty catchy and is be pretty well explained here: http://mike.pirnat.com/2009/05/09/the-diaper-pattern-stinks/. Good point about inability to catch some errors.

Answer (score 1):

If you are swallowing an exception, you're not stopping the third party page from breaking--your code was called and an exception happened, obviously the page is now broken--except now the developer of the third party page has no idea that your code broke. That's a big downside IMHO. If something bad happens, for goodness sake let someone know. That's what exceptions are for.

Answer (score 0):

Although I agree with Blender that ideally you would try to track any error by some thorough QA, to answer your question "What would be the downside effect":

- In term of performance, try-catch block have no effect when no error happen. And this does not depends on the size of the code. Try/catch have overhead effect only when an error happens. And the size of the code wouldn't increase/decrease this overhead significantly. Mostly the error handling will look at the return type of the caught block, not the whole block (have fun with [Page 96 of the ECMA specs](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm) : )
- @Aquinas has also a good point that other 3rd party scripts would need to know the page might be broken...

Comment: Your first point is simply not true.  Some JS engines (notably V8 in chrome) enter into a different (less performant) mode of handling the stack/heap variables when you are inside of a `try{}`.  Check the link that @steveax pointed out in the question please.